# Is there a framework for developing web and mobile apps using one code base?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I know that React.js is for web.
And I know that react-native is for Android/iOS.

Is there a way I can build ONE app (one code base) that will looks amazing (and native) for both web and mobile?

Comment: there's probably a way to use a react-native tool and [this](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) port to the web

Answer (score 2):

I think [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) is. It allows you to build awesome looking apps for web, iOS & android

Comment: I usually like to wait for other people to answer before accepting an answer- but I do like this answer.

Comment: The fact that the `react-native-web` tag on stackoverflow only received 36 questions this year makes me wonder if react-native-web is really ready for production, and if there is a large enough community of developers to form a viable ecosystem for production software. Thoughts??

Comment: yes, it is production ready AFAIK. Let's wait for other answers, maybe there is something here

Comment: What's an example of an app I can download from the app store and also view on the web? I want to get an idea of what react-native-web can do.

Answer (score 0):

Outside React, there is:

[htmx](https://htmx.org/)

[hotwired turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/native)

[hyperview](https://hyperview.org/)

These use native webview-component within the mobile-app to render html-website, which you can update separate from mobile-app-stores. Only native-code changes need updates to the app in the store. Cordova-, Phonegap- and Ionic-apps have been using webview for years, except they store the html-code inside the app that is distributed to the stores.

Or you can search for what [Progressive Web Apps (PWA)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) are and forget the mobile-app-stores completely. Or checkout [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/)